# How can I get SwiftUI List delete buttons to work? (or disappear)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list that allows deleting and moving. And there is an EditButton associated with the List :

```
struct IDLine: Identifiable, Codable {  
  let id: Int
  let line: String
}// IDLine


struct ContentView: View {
   ...
   @AppStorage("savedConversions") var conversions: [IDLine] = []
   ...

   var body: some View {
      ...
      List {
        ForEach(conversions) { Text($0.line) } // List of conversions
            .onDelete(perform: deleteConversion)
            .onMove(perform: moveConversion)
      }
    ...
}
    
func deleteConversion(at offsets: IndexSet) { conversions.remove(atOffsets: offsets) }
func moveConversion(from source: IndexSet, to dest: Int) { conversions.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: dest) }

}// ContentView
```

When I swipe left one of the rows of the List, a red rectangular Delete button appears at the right edge of the row. Clicking it does nothing. If I click on the EditButton, each row gets a round "-" button on the left, and again clicking it does nothing.
It's not all bad. If the left swipe on a row is taken far enough, deleteConversion gets called. And when the EditButton is pressed, the little 3-line grab handle appears at the right of each row allows the user to reorder the list.

Edit: I have added some more code to hopefully make it more self explanatory.

Comment: show us a complete example, that reproduces your problem, including  `deleteConversion`.

Comment: It sounds as view is not updated after you delete item from `conversions`, or you don't delete it at all.

Comment: In order to diagnose why the delete button wouldn't work, at the bare minimum, we'd need to see your `deleteConversion` function. In terms of your question about getting them to "disappear" -- just remove your `onDelete` modifier.

Comment: I see this as a bug in SwiftUI. The logically equivalent code in my older UIKit version works. The delete buttons that appear should be just alternative paths to invoke the deleteConversion function, but only of them seems to be hooked up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out what the problem was. I had an onTapGesture modifier on the VStack that the List was declared in. It was used to hide the keyboard. When I removed that modifier, the delete buttons started working again.
Here is a minimal application that has the problem:

```
import SwiftUI

struct IDLine: Identifiable, Codable {  // To allow SwiftUI List to correctly edit with repeated strings
  let id: Int
  let value: String
}// IDLine


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value: String = ""
    @State private var lines: [IDLine] = []
    @FocusState private var entryFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Enter value")
            TextField("value", text: $value).padding()
            .focused($entryFocused)
            HStack {
                Button("Add", action: addLine).disabled(value.count == 0)
                Button("Clear", action: clearLines).disabled(lines.count == 0)
                EditButton().disabled(lines.count == 0)
            }.padding(20)
            List {
                ForEach(lines) {
                  Text($0.value)
                }
               .onDelete(perform: deleteLine)
               .onMove(perform: moveLine)
            }
        }// VStack
        .onTapGesture { entryFocused = false }
    }// body

    func nextLine() -> IDLine {
        let id = 1 + lines.reduce(0) { Swift.max($0, $1.id) }
        return IDLine(id: id, value: value)
    }

    func addLine() { lines.append(nextLine()) }
    func clearLines() { lines = [] }
    func deleteLine(at offsets: IndexSet) { lines.remove(atOffsets: offsets) }
    func moveLine(from source: IndexSet, to dest: Int) { lines.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: dest) }

}
```